# F# -> Generic type - Multiple not struct

Tags: f#

My first thought was:

```
type ManyNavigationPropertyInfo<'a,'b>(cfg:ManyNavigationPropertyConfiguration<'a, 'b>) =
```

however it resolves `'a` and `'b` as `obj`, but it should be classes - therefore I did:

> type ManyNavigationPropertyInfo<'a
>   when 'a : not struct,'b when 'b : not
>   struct>(cfg:ManyNavigationPropertyConfiguration<'a,
>   'b>) =

but that just throws an error saying

> Unexpected symbol ',' in type name.
>   Expected '>' or other token.

What's the correct way for declaring such a type?

**UPDATE:**

My full code is:

```
type ManyNavigationPropertyInfo<'a,'b>(cfg:ManyNavigationPropertyConfiguration<'a, 'b>) =
    member x.WithMany (expr: Expr<'a -> ICollection<'b>>) = 
        cfg.WithMany(ToLinq(expr))
```

and it comes up with 2 compiler errors saying that `'a` and `'b` should be `not struct`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first thought is correct. You should be able to just write:

```
type ManyNavigationPropertyInfo<'a,'b>
       (cfg:ManyNavigationPropertyConfiguration<'a, 'b>) =
   // ...
```

The problem is probably somewhere later in the body of the type. From something that you wrote in the body, the compiler thinks that `'a` and `'b` must be of type `obj` (e.g. you're passing values of this type somewhere where `obj` is expected, or probably something more subtle).

You can try adding type annotations in the body of the class - this usually helps to find the issue, because the error message changes when you annotate the bit that F# compiler interprets differently than you expected.

To solve the immediate problem in your question - the syntax for specifying constraint is a bit different (first write all type variables and then constraints):

```
type ManyNavigationPropertyInfo<'a, 'b when 'a : not struct and 'b : not struct>( ... )
```

(But if you can post larger portion of code, maybe somebody can give a concrete advice.)